# Tortoise Hg: Configure mercurial to track only the size of the file for large files

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

Is there a function or extension in mercurial that will check and compare only the size of the file when it exceeds a certain amount? The largefiles extension doesn't seem to help me cause it still tracks the latest version of the large file. I want it to track the size only.

I know it's not that hard to implement as a script but I'm just checking if someone already did it before.

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing mercurial does out of the box.  There are a lot of edge cases whose behavior you're not describing (like: "what happens when a file was below the threshold and then later grows past it -- is it removed?")

You could, however, quite easily set up a precommit hook that writes the size of large files to a file that is tracked in your repo.  Something like this (untested) in your repo's `.hg/hgrc` would do it:

```
[hooks]
precommit.recordsize = find $(hg root) -type f -size 100M | xargs ls -l > $(hg root)/big_files
```

That would update a list of all the files greater than 100M in size in a file named `big_files` in the root of your repo along with their details.

Ignoring/not-committing the files could be done the same way.